# Multiple levels of macro variables resolve

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have email list in storage, which I include so that country specific people get notifications. But for demonstration purposes let use one:

I want to dynamically select address depending on variable &system:

```
%let SEList1 = "my.email@domain.eu";

%put system.list1.;
/*system.list1, which is ok*/
%put &system.list1.;
/*SElist1, which is ok*/
%put &&system.list1.;
/*SElist1, Hmm? Shouldn't this be "my.email@domain.eu"*/


%put &&&system.list1.;
/*"my.email@domain.eu", umm... ok? */
/*Lets keep going.... */

%put &&&&system.list1.;
/*SElist1. wut?  */
%put &&&&&system.list1.;
/*"my.email@domain.eu"*/
%put &&&&&&system.list1.;
/*"my.email@domain.eu"*/
%put &&&&&&&system.list1.;
/*&"my.email@domain.eu"*/
%put &&&&&&&&system.list1.;
/*SElist1. You got to be kidding me?*/
```

Question:

a)Why does not the && not resolve to address, but &&& does?

b)What on Earth is happening with levels of &*4+

Comment: Agreed. Duplicate question. Sorry. Search-fu had failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the SAS macro processor sees two ampersands `&&` it resolves that to one `&` and sets a flag that indicates it needs to reprocess the string for more macro variable resolutions.

So `&&&system.list1.` gets processed as `&&` , `&system.` and `list1.` which gives you an intermediate value of `&SElist1.`.  So on the second pass you get the value of your indirect macro variable reference.

> 178  %let SEList1 = "my.email@domain.eu";
>   179  %let system = SE ;
>   180  options symbolgen ;
>   181  %put &&&system.list1.;
>   SYMBOLGEN:  && resolves to &.
>   SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SYSTEM resolves to SE
>   SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SELIST1 resolves to "my.email@domain.eu"
>   "my.email@domain.eu"

If you only had two `&&` then the intermediate value is just `&system.list1.` which will split into `&system.` and `list1.` so the result should be `SElist1.`

You can add as many as you want and follow this rule. For example if you had 6 then after the first pass it would be the same as if you had started with 3 since each pair just gets reduced to one.  So using 6 yields the same result as using 3 but it just needs an extra pass at resolving the string.

Comment: Hmm. The logic seems to be right. Does it make sense? Well, that's up for debate I quess. Thanks anyways.